# Find an element on web page using C#

Tags: c#, getelementbyid

Helo!

My goal is to retreive data from HPE Service Manager (HPSM). I use webBrowser component as it's seems the easyest way to me. At least I had no problem with authorization and opening search page but the things turned strange as I proceeded.

I need to find element with id "X13" on the page but

```
wb.document.getElementById("X13");
```

returns null although executing getElementById in IE and Chrome dev consoles still does the trick.

How can I find the element I need using C# and webBrowser component?

Comment: Are you waiting for the page to finish loading?

Comment: Use htmlagilitypack lib, see [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Comment: are you sure your syntax is correct? your doing this in c# code correct?

Comment: Of course! To be sure here I event place my code in a button click handler.

Comment: what about wb.Document.GetElementDyId("X13"); In your c# code! the code you have above is JavaScript, your saying you are doing this in c#

Comment: HtmlElement he = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("X13");

Comment: did that work??

Comment: No GetElementById returns null in C#

Comment: The syntax was correct I just mistaked when retyping code here so the point is not about the syntax.  Still thanks for trying to help.  I even think it's some kind of protections HP uses to prevent robots to operate the application.